# nodejs Dúvida sobre module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Boa noite. Tenho uma dúvida talvez um tanto quanto simples mas que está me tirando o sono e creio que eu estou fazendo da maneira errada. Porém, se alguém puder corrigir e me explicar o pq eu errei eu serei grato.

Eu tenho um arquivo (módulo) do meu socket io no qual recebe via parametro alguns dados.. Porém, se eu dou um console nesses parametros **fora** do io.on('connection'.. me retorna tudo de acordo com o que eu enviei... Se eu tento retornar dentro do io.on('connection me retorna null ou undefined.. Pq? Não entendo.

Segue abaixo um trecho do código

```
module.exports = (io, path, method, status) => {

    console.log(path, method, status) // AQUI FUNCIONA O QUE RECEBI NESTE MODULO

    let users_online = 0
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log(path, method, status) // AQUI DENTRO JA ME RETORNA UNDEFINED
        users_online++
        io.emit('users_online', users_online)

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            users_online--
            io.emit('users_online', users_online)
        })
    })
}
```

Qual seria a solução? :(

Comment: Não faz sentido o console interior estar indefenido. Consegues criar um exemplo do problema aqui ou no https://codesandbox.io?

Comment: Então, Sergio, basicamente eu tenho o app.js na raiz com o seguinte codigo
```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    let route = req.url
    let method = req.method
    res.on('finish', () => {
        ws(io, route, method, res.statusCode)
    })
    next()
})
```
e esse middleware q dispara para o código do socket que está em config/ws.js
:(

Comment: de qualquer forma: https://github.com/rpelizza/socket-middleware